# How to authenticate for WordPress REST requests without username or password?

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I've been trying to come up with a way for a web app to be able to make post requests etc. to multiple WordPress sites, but i'm struggling with the authentication, issue is, I don't want to use login details as such.

I've tried using Basic, JWT etc. but they all require you to enter the username and password at some stage.

In an ideal world, I would love to just be able to store a random string somewhere in the wp-config or something, and be able to attach that as a header in the requests and have it authenticate, but I haven't been able to find anything similar, has anyone ever done anything similar to this?